# Сменить владеца файлов

Tags: bash, shell

в каталоге home/zadacha есть файлы с именами дат от 01.02.2018 до 01.08.2019 как сделать единой командой без ";" тоже самое если в любой части имени есть цифра 09 я сделал sudo find /home/zadacha -iname '09.*' -exec chown ivan:ivan {} \; вроде все нормально сработало. а вернули сказали что тут две команды а нужно все одной хоть будет и длинно. помогите как это понять.

Comment: `chown ivan:ivan /home/zadacha/*09*` может так попробовать?

Comment: Все работает спасибо

Comment: `сказали что тут две команды а нужно все одной` - в чем-то они правы. Вариант от @PotroNik правильный и мне нравится, но не учитывает одну вещь. `*` раскрывает командная оболочка и по факту выполняется `chown ... file1 file2 file3`. Если таких файлов очень много, оболочка не сможет выполнить команду - она будет огромедная. Есть такой момент

Comment: @TotalPusher, ты намекаешь на `find . -print0 | xargs -0`?

Comment: @donRumata, такой вариант также будет работать. Но я имел в виду `find ... exec`. Иначе раскрытие `*` оболочкой может привести к ошибке "список параметров слишком длинный". [Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands) подробно написано

Comment: @TotalPusher, ну так `xargs` как раз решает проблему слишком большой длины.

Comment: @donRumata, `xargs` для простых вещей не нужен, хотя есть разница с `find ... -exec ...`.